# How can I make the UID static in NFC hce app?

Tags: java, android, nfc, uniqueidentifier, hce

I'm creating an Android application using NFC and HCE technologies. Is it possible to make the UID static in such application? If that's the case, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at [Android API Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297139/how-can-i-make-the-uid-static-in-nfc-hce-app):

> In the first part of the exchange the HCE device will present its UID;
>   HCE devices should be assumed to have a random UID. This means that on
>   every tap, the UID that is presented to the reader will be a randomly
>   generated UID.

Nevertheless it's possible to make static UID editing Android source code, recompiling and flashing your device again. Nothing to easy.

 Also, using UID as unique card identifier it's not recommended.

Comment: There are so many contactless card-based services based on the card's UID that if it was too simple to set a phone's UID, we'd see a huge lot of trouble.